# Invariant Violation: Minified React error #152

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-native, react-redux

react_devtools_backend.js:2273 Invariant Violation: Minified React error #152; visit [http://reactjs.org/docs/error-decoder.html?invariant=152&args[]=t](http://reactjs.org/docs/error-decoder.html?invariant=152&args%5B%5D=t) for the full message or use the non-minified dev environment for full errors and additional helpful warnings.

This issue doesn't come when I run project localy but after deploying code on AWS server this issues can be seen in console.

Please help, and one thing more How can I debug this issue locally?

Answer (score 0):

This means nothing was returned from render, return statement is missing